# p:datagrid wont load data from view

Tags: primefaces, wildfly

Im using JAVA 10, WildFly 14, Primefaces 6.2

I am making a gift shop, this is the code of the grid in the xhtml file:

```
<p:dataGrid var="car" value="#{giftList.lgif}" columns="3" layout="grid"
    rows="12" paginator="true" id="gifts"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="6,12,16">
    <f:facet name="header">
        REGALOS
    </f:facet>
    <p:panel header="#{giftList.number}" style="text-align:center">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
            <p:graphicImage name="car.gif"/> 
                    <h:outputText id="out" value="#{giftList.text}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{giftList.number}" />

            <p:commandLink update=":form:carDetail" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" title="View Detail">
                <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search" style="margin:0 auto;" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{gifts}" target="#{giftList.lgif}" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>

</p:dataGrid>
```

I want the grid to display a list of gifts, i ahve two classes one named gift with name and price and other named giftlist that builds all the gifts:

gifts:

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.ajax;

public class gifts {

public String name;
public int price;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}}
```

giftList:

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.ajax;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.primefaces.showcase.view.ajax.gifts;

public class giftList {
private List<gifts> lgif;
private int numero =1;
private String text;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
    gifts gf = new gifts();
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    gf.setName("OSITO");
    gf.setPrice(40);
    lgif.add(gf);
}

 public int getGifts() {
        return lgif.size();
    }
public gifts getcurrentgift() {
     return lgif.get(0);
}   }
```

First I want that the value="" in the data grid be equal to #{giftList.lgif} the object that contains the gifts, for some reason it wont take the value I input, it only show something if the value is "1" or more, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there annotion for ManagedBean ou CDI on your class giftList: '@ManagedBean' or '@Named' and a scope '@ViewScoped' ?

Comment: I already fixed it, I added those two annotations and also I added the related bean to the faces-config.xml